# confusion with setting model in a route handler

Tags: ember.js

In the "Specifying a Route's Model" section of the Ember documentation, it says a controller's model property can be assigned by implementing the model hook in a route; it also says this behavior can be changed by implementing the setupController hook.  This led me to conclude that I can assign a model by doing one or the other.  But when I looked at the Ember documentation for "Setting Up a Controller," example shows the setupController hook requiring a function that takes two parameters: controller & model.  Documentation just says "model is the route handler's model.  For more information, see Specifying a Route's Model."  This leads me to conclude I need to do both steps.

If I don't need to do both steps, what's the difference between one vs. the other?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can simply override `model` and forget about `setupController`. Sometimes you don't need to override anything at all.

The default behaviour of `setupController` is to set the `model` property (which is aliased to the `content` property) of the controller to the current route's model (supplied as an argument). Usually this argument is the return value of the `model` hook, unless the route has a dynamic segment and is accessed via `{{linkTo}}`, `{{render}}`, or the like (ie. not directly from a url). In this case, the `model` hook is bypassed and `setupController` is given whatever model was supplied in the transition.

If your route has a dynamic segment, the `model` hook makes a guess at what you're looking for by default. Given a route path `something/:post_id`, the default `model` hook will return `App.Post.find(:post_id)`. If your route does not have a dynamic segment (e.g. `/posts`) then you have to override `model` to return the record(s) you want.

If you need to set additional properties beyond `model` or `content` on your controller, then you should override `setupController`. This will circumvent the default behaviour, so it is up to you to assign the model argument to the `model` or `content` property of your controller (or not). If you so choose, you may ignore the model argument altogether and set the controller's properties to whatever you like. The downside to this approach is that a model supplied by transition into a route with a dynamic segment will not get set on the controller.